# Titanium Studio 3.4.1.xx Android SDK missing

Tags: android, sdk, titanium

Titanium Studio 3.4.1.xx  tell me Android SDK is missing,
some error tips as following :

---

```
Node.js
  *  npm                new version v2.9.0 available! (currently v2.7.4)

Android Environment

  √√  tools              installed (v24.1.2)
  !  platform tools     untested version 22; may or may not work
  !  build tools        untested version 22.0.1; may or may not work

  !  ndk                Android NDK not found


Network
  √√  online
  -  no proxy server configured
```

What's wrong with it?

How to fix it?

Anyone help?

Comment: Windows 7 61bit, JDK 32bit (latest version)

Comment: have you checked http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix